# Port 80 in use. Try --listen PORT. Linux

Tags: linux, port, kill, port80

Port 80 is in use, so I was wondering how I could kill the process running on port 80.

Comment: I have tried running these commands in my terminal, however, it did not work.

Comment: sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 80 should give you the process and then you can  kill it. (Most like Apache or Nginx)

Comment: What's the output of `lsof -i:80`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try `netstat -tupln` to find the PID of your port.

Then you can use `kill PID` to terminate your job

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the `fuser` command is what you are looking for.

> `fuser -k [port]/[protocol]`

So, in your case:

> `fuser -k 80/tcp`

This utility was designed to identify processes using files or sockets. You may display the process information through

> `fuser 80/tcp`